# View has _Layout but dropdown menu isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a view that is using the Shared `_Layout` which has all of the stylesheets and javascript files referenced.

On my navbar I have a `dropdown-menu`:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Navigate<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuDivider">
```

But when I click on the dropdown, nothing happens.. the menu isn't displayed or anything.  When I click on the dropdown and move the cursor away the focus stays on the dropdown menu but again, nothing shows..

It looks like this:

[image]

This dropdown works on every other View except this one.

I have checked the *View Source* and all of the stylesheets & Javascript files from the `_Layout` are there.

This view gets created from an ajax call on another view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#SendToController').on('click', function() {
    sendToController();
    return false;
});
function sendToController(){
    var selectedM = $('#M').val();
    var chosenY = $('#Y').val();
    var chosenC = $('#C').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ALog/MReports/Generate',
        data: { 'mValue' : selectedM, 'y' : chosenY, 'c' : chosenC },
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("body").html(data);
        },
    });
}


</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It look like you have a duplicate ID somewhere else can you past your complete code ?

Comment: @Ersian Idk what else to post

Comment: Ok it help to explain, its because the DOM is not listening your new content, you have to reload it. `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` after your `$("body").html(data);` should fix the problem

Comment: @Ersian that worked, but I don't understand.. the DOM isn't listening to new content? reload it?

Comment: Yep I don't know how to explain properly but I got the same problem. When the JS is loaded and when new content come, it's not taken. Maybe you should use some event listener.

Comment: hmm that is strange, but that's a good idea. if you leave an answer i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your Ajax call the JS is not listening your new content, that why it's not working. You should "reload" your function after `$("body").html(data);` you can put `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` to make your dropdown menu working.